# Moving a player in Unity with Kinect data

Tags: sdk, unity-game-engine, kinect, accelerometer, move

So I bought an Oculus Rift to use for my final year project, and I thought it would be cool to make some sort of jogging simulator.
I was thinking of using the Kinect to detect when the player is jogging on the spot, and then move the player forward.
I was just wondering if anybody has any experience with the Kinect and what can be done with it.
If I was to use the Unity engine, could I use the Kinect to detect when the player is moving on the spot and then move the player forward?
Thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Unity plugins for Kinect that come with free trial/demo versions which you can use. I have used [ZigFu](http://zigfu.com/en/zdk/unity3d/), which works with different drivers (OpenNI, KinectSDK, etc.) and can detects players, their movements and even some gestures in an easy to use manner. Zigfu comes with some sample scenes which can help you understand how you can use it in your project very quickly. I have also used Omek Beckon SDK for a short while.

The biggest issue you will have is to detect user jogging. Player position data from Kinect is noisy and inaccurate, so you cannot directly use its values for detection of jogging. I guess some simple normalization on the data would be sufficient. Searching for "step detection from accelerometer" which is widely used in smartphones, and see how it works. You can apply the same principles to your case.